# Como posso compilar um simples programa em prolog?

Tags: prolog

Tenho o SWI-Prolog instalado, mas estou utilizando como uma especie de interpretador, exp:

`swi-pl?- [load].
True`

Gostaria de saber se existe um comando simples que eu possa usar via terminal para compilar o codigo fonte em um executavel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme o [SWI-Prolog.com](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/MakeExecutable.html):

> Para uso local, geralmente você não vai querer fazer um executável. Simplesmente crie um script, como descrito em [PrologScript](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/PrologScript.html), é fácil e inicia somente um pouco mais lento na maioria dos casos.
>   Um executável SWI-Prolog é um arquivo único que consiste de um executável nativo do sistema, com o *saved-state* junto a ele. *State* é criado usando [`qsave_program/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=qsave_program/2), como descrito no manual.

- [Executável para MS-Windows](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/WinExe.html):

Você pode fazer criar um `.exe` usando o `qsave_program/2` ou linha de comando.
A linha de comando abaixo cria myapp.exe a partir do load.pl e faz o programa iniciar a partir do `main/0`:

```
plcon -o myapp.exe -c load.pl --goal=main
```

Para executar o myapp.exe precisa que esteja na mesma pasta ou no `%PATH%` a `libpl.dll` e qualquer outra dll chamada no código.

- [Executável para sistemas Linux/Unix.](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/UnixExe.html)